# Fail to get data on using read() of StringIO in python

Tags: python, stringio

Using Python2.7 version. Below is my sample code.

```
import StringIO
import sys

buff = StringIO.StringIO()
buff.write("hello")
print buff.read()
```

in the above program, read() returns me nothing where as getvalue() returns me "hello". Can anyone help me out in fixing the issue? I need read() because my following code involves reading "n" bytes.

Comment: there's no function named `read()` in [stringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO)

Comment: @ChasingDeath: Yes there is. Try `dir(StringIO.StringIO)`.

Comment: yeah StringIO makes a file like object for strings so of course there would be `read()`

Answer (score 118):

You need to reset the buffer position to the beginning. You can do this by doing `buff.seek(0)`.

Every time you read or write to the buffer, the position is advanced by one. Say you start with an empty buffer.

The buffer value is `""`, the buffer pos is `0`.
You do `buff.write("hello")`. Obviously the buffer value is now `hello`. The buffer position, however, is now `5`. When you call `read()`, there is nothing past position 5 to read! So it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 29):

```
In [38]: out_2 = StringIO.StringIO('not use write') # be initialized to an existing string by passing the string to the constructor

In [39]: out_2.getvalue()
Out[39]: 'not use write'

In [40]: out_2.read()
Out[40]: 'not use write'
```

or

```
In [5]: out = StringIO.StringIO()

In [6]: out.write('use write')

In [8]: out.seek(0)

In [9]: out.read()
Out[9]: 'use write'
```

Comment: out.seek(0) is what was missing for me when I was trying to dump a pickle to StringIO and upload to s3. Once I pushed back to the beginning, my s3 object would be populated properly.