# Pandas to_csv(sys.stdout) doesn't work under my environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, pandas

I ran a following simple script:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
df.to_csv(sys.stdout)
```

### Expected Output (as standard output)

```
,0,1,2
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
```

However, I got no outputs on standard output by the program under Python 2.7.15 on macOS 10.12.6. Instead, it generated a file named `<stdout>` which contains the expected output.

Interestingly, on the same OS, Python 3.6.5 could show the result as standard output without any problems, and *virtualenved* Python 3.6.5 could not show it (and generated the `<stdout>` file).

Does anyone identify the cause of this result? The version of Pandas is 0.23.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21561

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21478

Answer (score 12):

Depending on what you are ultimately trying to do this workaround might or might not be useful:

```
In [85]: from io import StringIO

In [86]: output = StringIO()

In [87]: df.to_csv(output)

In [88]: print(output.getvalue())
,0,1,2
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
```

(Python 3.6)

For Python 2.7 replace the one line above with:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I think [this might be the 'proper' way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265593/fail-to-get-data-on-using-read-of-stringio-in-python):

```
In [3]: from io import StringIO

In [4]: output = StringIO()

In [5]: df.to_csv(output)

In [6]: output.seek(0)
Out[6]: 0

In [7]: print(output.read())
,0,1,2
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
```

Comment: FutureWarning: pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated as of 0.17.0, please use pyarrow.ipc.open_stream instead.

Comment: @AkshayHazari can you please explain your comment.  I don't see the connection to this answer.

Comment: When spark dataframe is converted to Pandas and then to_csv , it doesn't give the results but only this warning. 
But when I use `sys.stdout` instead of `StringIO()` it gave the required output along with the above warning.
Then I also turned the warnings off using `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')` to remove the above warning and only get the result